# Asymptotic bounds for $g(n)$, the number of Goldbach partitions of even integer $2n$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, goldbachs-conjecture

I explained in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473318/need-help-interpreting-this-formula-for-the-number-of-goldbach-partitions) how I got to this formula for $g(n)$, the number of Goldbach partitions of even integer $2n$:

$$g_{\left(n\right)}=\sum_{p\leq2n-3}\omega\left(2n-p\right)-\sum_{p\leq2n-3}\pi_{p,b}\left(2n-3p\right)$$

where $p$ is odd prime, $\pi_{a,b}\left(n\right)$ denotes the number of primes of the form $ak+b$ less than or equal to $n$ and:

$$b=\left(2n-3p\right)\mod p$$

Now I used the following asymptotic relations:

$$\omega\left(n\right)\sim\log\log n$$
$$\pi_{p,b}\left(n\right)\sim\frac{\pi\left(n\right)}{\varphi\left(p\right)}\sim\frac{\pi\left(n\right)}{p-1}$$

which gives me this:

$$g_{\left(n\right)}\sim\sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\log\log\left(2n-p\right)-\sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\frac{\pi\left(2n-3p\right)}{p-1}$$

Now we know that if $p$ is a prime factor of $n$, then $\pi_{p,b}\left(2n-3p\right)=1$, so:

$$\sum_{_{2<p\leq2n-3}}\frac{\pi\left(2n-3p\right)}{p-1}$$

would be the maximum value for:
$$\sum_{_{p\leq2n-3}}\pi_{p,b}\left(2n-3p\right)$$

and will occur when $n$ have no prime factor $\leq\frac{2n-3}{3}$. In fact, a very accurate estimation is:

$$\sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\pi_{p,b}\left(2n-3p\right)\sim\sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\frac{\pi\left(2n-3p\right)}{p-1}-\sum_{p>2,p\mid n}\frac{\pi\left(2n-3p\right)}{p-1}$$

**Question 1:**

When we look at the graph for:
$$\sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\pi_{p,b}\left(2n-3p\right)$$

in red, and

$$ \sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\log\log\left(2n-p\right) $$

in green:

[image]

It looks like the following holds for large $n$:
$$\sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\pi_{p,b}\left(2n-3p\right)<\sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\log\log\left(2n-p\right)$$

I computed up to $10^7$ and it holds for all $n>41011$

Does anyone have an idea on how to prove this?

**Question 2:**

Looking at the asymptotic result for $g(n)$, It also looks like a lower bound:

$$ g\left(n\right)>\sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\log\log\left(2n-p\right)-\sum_{2<p\leq2n-3}\frac{\pi\left(2n-3p\right)}{p-1}$$

[image]

This one holds for all $n>2$. Of course this one should be harder to prove because it would prove Goldbach's conjecture. Any idea on how it could or could not be possible to prove those bounds ?

Also, I came up with this formula myself, but I haven't found anything similar on the web yet, so it would also be helpful if someone could think of some related work I could read.

Comment: Your question is unclear, search about the [circle method](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161947/what-keeps-asymptotic-goldbachs-conjecture-out-of-reach-of-current-technology), the only known attack towards estimates for the Goldbach function $R(2n)=\sum_{2n=a+b}\Lambda(a)\Lambda(b)$ decomposed in two terms (major arc $\sim\frac{Cn}{\log n}$ and minor arc) and why the minor arc term gets smaller only for the ternary version $R_3(n)=\sum_{n=a+b+c}\Lambda(a)\Lambda(b)\Lambda(c)$. Also look at what is predicted by the random model for the primes.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for your comment i'll look into that.

Comment: Goldbach partitions can exceed $n-\omega(2n)+1$ at most. it's hit at least once.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I don't understand your comment, can you elaborate a little bit ?

Comment: $p,q$ can't be divisors of $2n$, 2 isn't counted as it's not odd.